# Prove that the phase retrieval problem is non-convex

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares, non-convex-optimization, inverse-problems

The  **phase retrieval problem** consists of recovering phase information from given intensity measurements, as shown in the image below from [Deep phase retrieval: analyzing over-parameterization in phase retrieval](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.sigpro.2020.107866).

---

[image]

---

I don't understand why it is a non-convex optimization problem. Can someone please help me on how to prove it? Or is there any paper or book about this topic?

Comment: You may want to take a look at Emmanuel Candès's [lecture at ISIT 2013](https://youtu.be/A3HkQ6zyr8E?t=398).

Comment: Thank you very much Rodrigo. Both for helping me edit the question and give me some suggestion. Sorry, i am new to stack exchange.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the simple example where $n = 1$, $m = 1$, $a_1 = 1$, $y_1 = 1$, i.e. we are estimating a $1$-dimensional complex variable $z \in \mathbb{C}$ from one measurement $1 = |z|^2$.

Then, $f(z) = (1-|z|^2)^2$, which satisfies $f(1)=f(-1) = 0$, but $f(0) = 1$. Hence, $$f\left(\dfrac{-1+1}{2}\right) = f(0) = 1 > 0 = \dfrac{0+0}{2} = \dfrac{f(-1)+f(1)}{2},$$ and thus, $f$ is not convex.

Comment: Thank you. Now i understand that it is not non-convex optimization. For example if i draw the picture of $(1-(x^2+y^2))^2$. Around the (x,y)=(0,0). There is a peak. However, even it is non-convex, i guess this function can still be solved by gradient descent. Because there is no saddle point here. Why this problem become so hard to solve. Some people say it is non-convex quadratic programming problem.

Comment: I don't understand the general idea how to prove or find example that the function or the set is non-convex. Can you explain more about your general idea in your prove about one function is non-convex.  Thank you.

Comment: A function $f$ is convex iff $f(tx+(1-t)y) \le tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ for all $x,y$ in the domain of $f$ and all $t \in [0,1]$. To show that a function $f$ is non-convex, we just need to find an example where $f(tx+(1-t)y) > tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ for some $x,y$ in the domain of $f$ and some $t \in [0,1]$. To find the specific example I did, I just started with the simplest case, and that happened to work.

Comment: Get it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit strange to "blame" the non-convexity on the "square modulus operation"  here. The least-squares phase retrieval problem can be casted even without the square on the modulus, yet it would still be non-convex. The issue here is that both the maps $\mathbf{z} \mapsto y_r - |\mathbf{a}_r ^* \mathbf{z} |$ and $\mathbf{z} \mapsto y_r - |\mathbf{a}_r ^* \mathbf{z} |^2$, despite being concave, are / can be negative for certain values of $\mathbf{z}$ (that will depend on $\mathbf{a}_r$); thus the non-convexity arises when they are composed with a convex non-monotonic function (i.e. $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^2$).